# How to delete top (1) row from SQL if row count reached to 10000

Tags: sql-server

I have made fault history log into HMI through SQL database,
I am  deleting top row by PLC TAG by using following code

```
DELETE TOP (10) PERCENT FROM [dbo].[ABC]
```

I want to delete first row while my row-count reached to 10000
in other way to say that ....
a new fault record add in log and first old record should delete and so on...

Comment: If you think that this or any other answer is the best solution to your problem, you may [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it. Only one answer can be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

If I understansd you correctly, you need to number the rows using `ROW_NUMBER()` and then execute appropriate `DELETE` and `INSERT` statements:

```
DELETE t
FROM (
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PLC DESC) RN
   FROM [dbo].[ABC]
) t
WHERE RN >= 10000

INSERT [dbo].[ABC] (PLC) VALUES (...)
```